# How to show an icon on last index of flat list

Tags: react-native, flexbox, styles, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to wrap my flat list and trying to show an Icon after last index of Flatlist. I had tried but it works fine on a single row. when we data goes to next row it would not work.

Here is my flat list code. **Modal** and **Input** both are my custom component.

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return (
   <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.tagPostContainer, styles.viewTagContainer]}>
      <AppText
        type={'input'}
        label={`#${item}`}
        color={colors.placeholder}
        containerStyle={[styles.tagPostInactiveTxt, styles.BgAddedTag]}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

return(
 <>
 <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>
 <FlatList
      data={tags}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.TagFlatlist}
    />
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.plusIconContainer}
          onPress={() => setVisible(true)}>
          <CreateBuildIconFocus height={13} width={13} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
 <Modal
    visible={visible}
    buttonLabel={'Done'}
    containerWidth={width / 1.7}
    onCancel={onCancel}
    onSubmit={onClick}
    containerHeight={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 200 : 200}>
    <Input
      placeholder={'Add Tags'}
      autoFocus={true}
      minWidth={120}
      maxWidth={150}
      value={tag}
      onChangeText={text => setTag(text)}
    />
  </Modal>
 
 </>
)
```

FlatList styles:

```
TagFlatlist: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
```

Here is my design screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution for this. You can implement `ListFooterComponent` that used for showing something on end of flatlist. [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#listfootercomponent) you can see more details of `ListFooterComponent`.

Here are the code of Flatlist.

```
return(
   <FlatList
      data={tags}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      ListFooterComponent={
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.plusIconContainer}
          onPress={() => setVisible(true)}>
          <CreateBuildIconFocus height={13} width={13} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }
      contentContainerStyle={styles.TagFlatlist}
    />
)
```